# How to enable GZIP on blogger OR how to increase blogger speed if using too many script?

Tags: javascript, compression, gzip, blogger, blogspot

I have been looking for these solution for 3 weeks, and it seem like nobody care about it. Is it possible to enable gzip on blogger? If not, how to increase blogger speed if I'm using too many script?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to speed up your blog using then you will be glad to know that blogger has built-in html compressor you don't need to use gzip. You can check your blog's compression ability using this tool http://checkgzipcompression.com/

You can apply some tips which can speed up your blog such as:

(1). Remove all the unwanted gadgets from your blog, keep only useful gadgets. Try to add as less gadgets as you can.

(2). Use optimized(small size) images in your blog.

(3). Remove inline-css codes.

(4). Take all of your css and javascript codes to "head" part in template.

(5). Use lazy load script for images.

(6). Remove render blocking scripts from your blog and also external css sources which are slowing down your blog. You can use Google page insights to check which script is slowing down your blog.

(7). Remove third-party ads.

Source: http://101helper.blogspot.com/2014/08/how-to-speed-up-your-blog.html

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to provide more explanation to your answers. If that link dies, this answer becomes useless to future SO users. Please provide the tips here, while still maintaining attribution to the original author. See [How to answer page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for help in improving your answer.

Comment: Sorry I am new to stackoverflow, I know this problem because I also use blogger so I told him what I did for my own blog.

Comment: I understand, I meant you should post the _contents_ of that blog post here on Stack Overflow as well. I know you will try your best to make sure that blog never goes offline, but in case it does, it would be helpful to future users of Stack Overflow to have that content here as well.

Comment: You can summarize it quite a bit, but try to include the really relevant bits.

Comment: I have made changes in my answer, I hope its ok now

Comment: @FahimRaza your answer is not relevant to quotation it about how to enable gzip in blogger

Answer (score 0):

Gzip is a good compression method to reduce the http request size and there by decreasing page load time.

If your blog is hosted in google blogspot / blogger, then you don't have to worry about gzip compression of your blog because google does it by default to all the blogs.

To confirm, there are many online tools available to check if gzip compression is enabled to your blog. It is checked by analyzing the header response for your blog.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add it on the blogger blog, I also tried it on my blog https://www.assameselyrical.com/ but no success.

So, I removed all unused CSS, widgets from the sidebar, optimize large images files, and integrated [ezoic](https://ezoic.com/) with [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/).

Finally, my site [Assamese Lyrical](https://www.assameselyrical.com/) loading speed is quite good.

Answer (score -2):

Try this. It work fr BLOGGER

```
<?php if (substr_ count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'],'gzip')) ob_start("ob_gzhandler");else ob_ start();?>
```

Paste on top before this code (like this)

```
<!DOCTYPE html
```

.
I give you ilustration

[image]
Then test your blogger (Blogger using .xml)
Test in here: http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php

You need Evidence? I also do it yourself and the effect is remarkable increase speed blog
[image]